# Creating a binary tree from an array

Tags: c++, template, pointers

I want to easily create a binary tree given an array. The array elements are processed in a level order manner. E.g. If the array contains:

{19,10,43}

Then the root is 19, left child is 7 and right child is 3. To declare that the node does not have a child, I'm using a special data value as infinity marker.

E.g. {19,10,43,7,12,END_MARKER,50} becomes like this:

```
    19
   /  \
  10  43
 / \    \    
7   12  50
```

here, 43 has no left child because it is marked by END_MARKER.

The function that does the conversion is as follows:

```
/*
 * Create a BST from the given vector. Use nullMarker to specify that the data element
 * does not exist. For example, if there is no left child of a node, place nullMarker as it's value.
 * When passing the initVector to create bst, follow the heap property.
 */
template <typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(const vector<T>& initVector,T nullMarker) {

    if(initVector.size() == 0 || initVector[0] == nullMarker)
        return;

    queue<reference_wrapper<unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>>>> q;
    this->root = make_unique<BinarySearchNode<T>>(initVector[0]);
    q.emplace(this->root);

    size_t lastIndex = initVector.size()-1;

    size_t index = 0; // MUST start with index = 0
    while (!q.empty() && (index + 2) < lastIndex) {

        auto current = q.front();

        T left = initVector[index+1];
        T right = initVector[index+2];


        if(left != nullMarker) {
            current.get()->leftChild = make_unique<BinarySearchNode<T>>(left);
            q.emplace(current.get()->leftChild);
        }

        if(right != nullMarker) {
                current.get()->rightChild = make_unique<BinarySearchNode<T>>(right);
                q.emplace(current.get()->rightChild);
        }

        index+=2;
        q.pop();
    }

    // Two possible cases
    // 1. There is one left child remaining.
    // 2. There are no more

    if(index != lastIndex) {
        auto current = q.front();

        if(initVector[++index] != nullMarker) {
            current.get()->leftChild = make_unique<BinarySearchNode<T>>(initVector[index]);
        }

        index++;

        if(index <= lastIndex) {
            current.get()->rightChild = make_unique<BinarySearchNode<T>>(initVector[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

BinarySearchNode is created but I'm thinking I should call it binary node instead.

BinaryTree class is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class BinaryTree {
public:
    BinaryTree(const vector<T>& initVector,const T nullMarker);
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>>& getRoot() { return root; }
private:
    void populateBinaryNode(BinarySearchNode<T>& parent, vector<T> source);
private:
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> root = nullptr;
};
```

BinarySearchNode itself is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class BinarySearchNode {

public:
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> leftChild;
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> rightChild;

    BinarySearchNode(T pData) : data(pData), leftChild(nullptr), rightChild(nullptr) {}
    BinarySearchNode(T pData, unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> pLeft, unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> pRight)
    : data(pData),leftChild(move(pLeft)), rightChild(move(pRight)) {}

    T getData() const { return data; };

private:
    T data;
};
```

Following is an example of how I'm using it:

```
int END_MARKER = numeric_limits<int>::min();

BinaryTree<int> bst(
                    {
                        19, // 0 l = 1, r = 2
                        7, // 1 l = 3, r = 4
                        43, // 2 l = 5, r = 6
                        3,  // 3 l = 7, r = 7
                        11, // 4 l = 9, r = 10
                        23, // 5 l = 11, r = 12
                        47, // 6 l = 13, r = 14
                        2,  // 7 l = 15, r = 16
                        5,  // 8 l = 17, r = 18
                        END_MARKER, // 9
                        17, // 10 l = 21, r = 22
                        END_MARKER, // 11
                        37, // 12 l = 25, r = 26
                        END_MARKER, // 13
                        53, // 14 l = 28
                        END_MARKER,
                        END_MARKER,
                        END_MARKER,
                        END_MARKER,
                        13,
                        END_MARKER,
                        29,
                        41,
                        END_MARKER,
                        END_MARKER,
                        END_MARKER,31
                    },
                    END_MARKER);
```

Comment: That kind of sentinel won't work well for a general value `T`.  Simply using `nullptr`'s for the left and right node should suffice.

Comment: I used the sentinel so the user can pass the right sentinel for the general data type T. Since the array which I'm parsing to convert to tree contains only data value of type T, I don't know how to specify a nullptr. I looked at the C++ standard reference, nullptr is a nullptr_t which is a null pointer constant. I'm not sure if I can pass a nullptr in a non-pointer data types? I will append my question with how I'm using the DS.

Comment: But there might be `T`'s that doesn't allow the user to determine a reasonable one, so your generic implementation would become useless for them.

Comment: That is right. Can you please suggest how I might work around? I cannot insert nullptr in a vector of int or generic datatype T. Is there an idiomatic way or a pattern I can use. The only other thing, I can think of is to have a seperate list of indices which serves as end marker. So if I want to say {19,-,25} and I want to say 19 has no left child then i can pass sentinel array {1}, here since index 1 is in the sentinel array, it means it is being treated as a sentinel. It burdens the user though and makes it harder to use.

Comment: You already have those `unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>>` for the `leftChild` and `rightChild` members. A `std::unique_ptr` can hold a `nullptr`, so why hassling with the sentinel value at all?

Comment: The use case is, take an array and create a Binary Tree. Yes, left and right nodes can be nullptr's because they are of type smart pointers pointing to object of type T. They themselves can point to nullptr. That's allowed. But the array which is being parsed need to indicate somehow that the left or right child is missing and it cannot do that using nullptr.

Comment: So you probably have a design flaw in your client API. Think of something alternate. Hint: You could wrap your `T` value with an internal helper class/struct.

Comment: I know that there is a limitation in the design and it is by design so far.  If an extreme value such as the smallest min or largest max is going to be used, heuristically, in most cases the user might not have chosen the appropriate data type large enough for the data set.  Also, see there is only one constructor that requires a sentinel, forcing the user to make the decision about the right sentinel. So depending on somebody's use case it can or cannot be appropriate.

Comment: What about `T == std::string` for example? _"...  or cannot be appropriate."_ That's a bad user experience, I'd try to avoid that, or communicate clear concepts what `T` actually can be or not.

Comment: hmm, why can't someone use "NULL" or whatever they deem fit as a null marker in the string case? C++ standard requires overloaded comparison operator for ==, `template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator> 
      bool operator==(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
                      const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs) noexcept;`

Comment: An empty `std::string` might be considered a valid value (there's nothing like a string NULL value, common problem with mapping native DB values BTW). As mentioned, your API design is flawed and restricted. If you have restrictions by design and intended, prove these with applying a concept check for `T`.

Comment: Ok, I understand but like I mentioned, for the time being, it's part of the design to make it quick and easy. I'll try to think of something that can wrap a sentinel without compromising the ease, also my idea of accepting another collection of indices. I've considered the ideas you mentioned before and know won't work for me and will probably just be a case of death by overdesign.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think you are understanding.  The function is not going to save the user from wrong usage. If someone expects their data to have empty strings and they choose empty string as a sentinel that's their problem.

Comment: I understood well what you're doing. I think you aren't able to catch up with my point: Leaving _the problem_ to your client isn't a good generic API design. Your customer is king, serve them as gently as possible.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are wrong about that, standard library provides plenty of templated containers and methods where the user uses the flexibility to use it right or not. It's a compromise between flexibility and what is allowed.  Anyways, thanks for your suggestions. I'm interested in hearing ideas from other experienced people, perhaps there is an idiomatic way of doing it better.

Comment: Well, so I'll shut up now and leave room for other peoples opinion. The standard library stuff, does concept checks BTW. I said communcating the intended use that way _is fine_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I just got an idea of what I can do seamlessly but may have more overhead. Will post when I get a chance to code it.

Comment: Things like type traits and concept checks come without almost any cost. Just add another layer of indirection to represent `T` internally.

Comment: that's a good idea. I will look into it but I have to read up on that.